# How to send image using push notification?

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

How to send push notification with the image using FCM, I have used below things but still just getting only title and text in the notification.

I have used cordova based hybrid application. If anyone has any idea, please let me know.

Sample curl code:

```
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -X POST \
--header "Authorization: key=<AUT KEY>" \
--Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '
 {
   "to": "<to TOKEN>"
   "notification":{
     "title":"New Notification!",
     "body":"Test",
     "color":"#ff0000",
     "icon":"noti_icon",
     "img_url": "https://static.pexels.com/photos/4825/red-love-romantic-flowers.jpg",
     "image"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
    "avatar_url"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
    "url"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
    "image_url"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
    "largeIcon":"http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
   },
   "data" : {
      "img_url": "https://static.pexels.com/photos/4825/red-love-romantic-flowers.jpg",
      "image"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
      "avatar_url"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
      "url"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
      "image_url"  : "http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
      "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API",
      "largeIcon":"http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
      "main_picture":"http://cernyyachtdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/png-test.png",
    },
   "priority":1
 }'
```

[image: Like this screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: how do you know that `just getting only title and text in notification.`? How you check?

Comment: Caused, i am getting notification in my phone with title and body text.

Comment: Do you want to see screenshot then i will attached?

Comment: `"icon":"noti_icon"` this will set the icon `noti_icon` resource. Do you have such resource?

Comment: Yes, I have that resources and notification icon is also display.
But I want to send notification image.

Comment: Have you added code for downloading image from provided url and show in Notification?

Comment: I am just used above curl code to send notification, will i need to add any other code for display image in notification?

Comment: it won't show by default, `img_url` is not a field of the notification object, therefore it doesn't know what to do with it. You have to manually download it and show the custom notification

Comment: Can you have any sample code or demo which can handle this things?

Comment: This solution maybe of help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575963/4206951

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 2 days suffer, I got solution to display all types of notification in cordova application.

Plugin Details: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Make sure you have to remove cordova-plugin-firebase if you want to user above plugin, else it will conflict with each other.

For more detail please check above git link which have detail flow of this plugin. I have tested it on android@8.0.0