# FCM push notification - image not push

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic-native

I have a problem, I am trying to send FCM notification by [http](https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send). When I send below payload:

```
{
     "notification" : {
         "body" : "test Notification",
         "title": "test Notification",
         "image" : "https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360"
     },


"to":"firebasetoken",
"priority":"high"
```

}

I get notification on my mobile devices but the notification contains only Title and Body. I tried changing image to imageurl but that also didn't work.

I want display my notification as below.

[image]

I will be grateful for help. I tried at the beginning of last year and this payload was good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase FCM notification image won't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481191/firebase-fcm-notification-image-wont-show)

Comment: are you using nodejs? and what library?

Comment: I use Ionic4 with native push notification lib (@ionic/fcm/ngx)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using legacy HTTP API which doesn't support image payload. Try migrating to HTTP v1 API and you'll be able to send image payload. Follow these links.
[Migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1).
[Send image in notification payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image)

When migrating to HTTP v1, you'll need oAuth token and in case you don't know how to generate it, I'll provide step by step guide here.

**To create oAuth token, follow these steps.**
Step 1. Get serviceaccount json file from firebase console.
Go to firebase console -> project setting -> service account tab and click generate new private key to download json file. The json file contains some credential information.

Step 2. Generate token
Generating token will require running some program code using node,python or java and here I'll be using node.
Create generatekey.js file with below code, and change path of json file inside code.

```
var {google} = require("googleapis");

// Load the service account key JSON file.
var serviceAccount = 
require("path/to/downloaded.json"); //change path to your downloaded json file

// Define the required scopes.
var scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"
 ];

// Authenticate a JWT client with the service account.
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(serviceAccount.client_email,
null,serviceAccount.private_key,scopes);

// Use the JWT client to generate an access token.
jwtClient.authorize(function(error, tokens) {
if (error) {
  console.log("Error making request to generate access token:", 
  error);
} else if (tokens.access_token === null) {
console.log("Provided service account does not have permission to generate access tokens");
} else {
  var accessToken = tokens.access_token;
  console.log(accessToken);

  // See the "Using the access token" section below for information
  // on how to use the access token to send authenticated requests to
  // the Realtime Database REST API.
}
});
```

Run generatekey.js file from terminal with command
**node genereatekey.js** and it will print OAuth2 token.

Comment: Thanks for help - i was wondering it is a couse that. I read manual but i have problem because I don't know how i can generate bearer auth2.0 key. (Its is very complicate)

Comment: I updated my answer and see how to generate OAuth2 token.

Comment: Chan Myae Aung  thanks for help. Tell me on one question. MustI generate always new OAuth2 token per user? Is it enough to generate it only once?

Comment: Generate only one but you'll need to regenerate once it's expired.

Comment: @ChanMyaeAung how long does it take to expire?

Comment: about 1 hour!
response from https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{"access_token":"*******************************","expires_in":3599,"token_type":"Bearer"}

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const message = {
         "notification" : {
            "body" : "test Notification",
            "title": "test Notification",
         "android": {
            "notification": {
             imageUrl: 'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360'}
}
```

Comment: I tried imageURL but it is not working!